# How to write boolean function in a single line in C#?

Tags: c#

```
public bool IsNewUser(int id)
{
  var data= DataContext.Employee.Where(e=>e.id==id).FirstorDefault();
  if(data==null)
     return true;
  return false;
}
```

How can I write the above function logic using maybe  `??` or something else in a single line  in C#? I am sure that must be possible just can't think right now..Thanks

Comment: You seem to be confusing the null coalescing operator (??) with the ternary (?:), the latter can help you here.  ?? is for using an alternative result when an evaluation might be null.

Comment: Yea..my bad..friday afternoons are tough !

Comment: also, the `Any` method is golden here. You wouldn't need the ternary here either, you could just return `Context...FirstOrDefault() == null`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This wouldn't be a case to use `??` but this should help:

```
public bool IsNewUser(int id)
{
    return !DataContext.Employee.Any(e => e.id == id);
}
```

`??` would be used doing something like this:

```
public Employee GetEmployeeOrNew(int id)
{
    return DataContext.Employee.Where(e => e.id == id).FirstorDefault() ?? new Employee();
}
```

Comment: data == null should return true, not false.

Comment: @Seva - yeah, forgot the context of the method `IsNewUser`

Answer (score 3):

```
return (null == DataContext.Employee.Where(e=>e.id==id).FirstorDefault());
```

Answer (score 3):

```
return DataContext.Employee.Where(e=>e.id==id).FirstorDefault() == null;
```

`??` is the null coalescing operator, used to assign a default value instead of null. IE

```
data = data ?? GetNonNullData();
```

[`?:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx) is the ternary conditional, probably what you were thinking of. But it's not actually necessary in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The Any operator would be more appropriate than FirstOrDefault:

```
public bool IsNewUser(int id)
{
   return !DataContext.Employee.Any(e => e.id == id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `Any` method instead of the `Where...FirstOrDefault` construct:

```
public bool IsNewUser(int id)
{
  return !DataContext.Employee.Any(e=>e.id==id);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
return !DataContext.Employee.Any(e=>e.id==id);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return data == null ? true : false;
```

Comment: or `return DataContext.Employee.Where(e=>e.id==id).FirstorDefault() == null ? true : false;` I think.

Comment: -1: first, the conditional operator is extraneous. Second, need to initialize `data` first. The OP specifically asked for a one-line function, not for replacing the last three lines with one.

Answer (score 0):

```
return DataContext.Employee.Any(e => e.id == id);
```